# Is there a way to specify the order of available commands in fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

Is there a way to specify the order that commands are listed when you execute `fab -l`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it: the [source](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/blob/master/fabric/main.py#L355) seems to just sort the list of names. (See also the docstring for the `_task_names` function just after that.)

As an obvious follow-up, what kind of sorting are you looking for? Could you simply postprocess the output of `fab -l`?

Comment: The sorting I am after would be something closer to the order I defined the tasks. In this particular case, I have a task that I will not use frequently, but because of the way I named it, it sits near the top of the list. I will would rather have it near the end.